# Create universal iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode7

I have created a universal iOS-framework. In Xcode, it is an "Aggregate target" which uses a build script and the `lipo` command line tool to put iphonesimulator- and iphoneos-binaries into just one container binary. The command for building the iphonesimulator-binary is

```
xcodebuild -project MMFramework.xcodeproj -scheme "$SCHEME_NAME" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build \
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator
```

(I have replaced the name of the project with "MMFramework", but this is not the problem.)

When using Xcode 6, the iphonesimulator binary builds without a problem. When using Xcode 7 I get errors, like e.g.

```
// (with Xcode 7)
#import <sys/utsname.h>
^^Error: Could not build module 'Darwin'
```

Furthermore, xcodebuild behaves differently in Xcode7. Xcode 6 translates my xcodebuild command to calls like

```
# with Xcode 6
CompileC build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/MPThreadIdAtom.o MPThreadIdAtom.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Xclang -fmodule-implementation-of -Xclang MMFramework -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-generated-files.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-project-headers.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/MPThreadIdAtom.d --serialize-diagnostics /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/MPThreadIdAtom.dia -c /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/MPThreadIdAtom.m -o /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/MPThreadIdAtom.o
```

But with Xcode 7, you can see that it finally believes that the iphonesimulator runs on the ARM platform. It seems to be confused wether it wants to build an iphonesimulator- or an iphoneos-binary.

```
# With Xcode 7
CompileC build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MPThreadIdAtom.o MPThreadIdAtom.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Xclang -fmodule-implementation-of -Xclang MMFramework -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -iquote /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-generated-files.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/MMFramework-project-headers.hmap -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/DerivedSources -F/Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MPThreadIdAtom.d --serialize-diagnostics /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MPThreadIdAtom.dia -c /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/MPThreadIdAtom.m -o /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/build/Intermediates/MMFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/iOSMMFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MPThreadIdAtom.o
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Volumes/Development/myProject/frameworks/MMFramework/MPThreadIdAtom.h:9:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
```

So, has anyone built a universal iOS framework with Xcode 7 successfully? Or did I make some mistake?

Xcode 7 is the selected version on my system:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

It is installed under /Applications/Xcode.app, and Xcode 6 lives under /Applications/Xcode6.app .

---

Here is my build script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "XXX 0"

######################
# Options
######################


FRAMEWORK_NAME="MMFramework"
SCHEME_NAME="iOSMMFramework"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"
FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################

echo "XXX 1"

xcodebuild -project MMFramework.xcodeproj -scheme "$SCHEME_NAME" -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1

echo "XXX 2"

xcodebuild -project MMFramework.xcodeproj -scheme "$SCHEME_NAME" -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1

######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

echo "XXX 3"

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

echo "XXX 5"

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Make an universal binary
######################

echo "XXX 7"

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo

echo "XXX 8"

# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
    cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi

if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
    cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
fi

echo "XXX 9"
```

and my Xcode universal target contains two build phases: "Target Dependencies (0 items)", and "Run Script". The Script is:

```
iOSMMFramework/universal-buildscript.sh 2>&1 |tee ~/my-log.txt
```

the my-log.txt is just for debugging, and that is where I got the logfiles from.

Xcode 6 has an SDKROOT of "iphonesimulator8.4", Xcode 7 has an SDKROOT of "iphonesimulator9.2".

And I have customized the build folder location to PROJECT_DIR/build. (Changing it back to the default location doesn't make a difference though.)

---

With Xcode 7.2 (7C68) it does NOT work. With Xcode 6.4 (6E35b) it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same command and able to create universal framework.

```
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${TARGET_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}"
```

Can you try removing the clean build command from xcodebuild? I use different shellscript.